# How to specify GStreamer version for Qt

Tags: c++, qt, gstreamer, yocto

I am using UVC camera for testing the Qt Camera sample program on Freescale Yocto.

```
Enviroment:  
 Qt 5.3  
 Yocto Poky 1.6.2
```

Got the error like this when running, and no video output

```
    ERROR: v4l2 capture: slave not found!

(gst-plugin-scanner:1523): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'GstVorbisDec'

(gst-plugin-scanner:1523): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed

(gst-plugin-scanner:1523): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_register: assertion 'g_type_is_a (type, GST_TYPE_ELEMENT)' fERROR: v4l2 capture: slave not found!
ailed
```

There is two version GStreamer was found in the Yocto system:

```
gst-launch imxv4l2src ! imxv4l2sink      //don't work
gst-launch-1.0 imxv4l2src ! imxv4l2sink  //got camera video output
```

So how to specify Qt using GStreamer1.0

Comment: Make that bitbake scenario to use: https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/44999/

Comment: Please mention at least the version of yocto, version of QT and the layer QT comes from.

Comment: You can have a look at https://github.com/GStreamer/qt-gstreamer